# PDF-to-JSON converter

Tags: ruby, parsing, converting, json, pdf

I've created some methods to help me convert PDF to text and then text to a JSON object. I've never done this before and I'm using this exercise as a way to improve my knowledge of Ruby.

The following code does what I want, it works. It just returns a very ugly object. Right now I'm trying to craft some regular expressions to help produce cleaner objects. In the meantime, I'd love some feedback on how to improve what I've got so far.

```
require "pdf_outliner/version"
# Regexes
# words: /\A[\w{*}]+[\s]/
# sentences: /^[A-Z]+[\S\s]+[.?!]/
# paragraphs: 
# outline headings (I., A.,, etc): /^[A-Za-z1-9]+\./

module PdfOutliner

  def pdf_to_text(pdf, file)
    File.open(file, 'w') do |f|
      pdf.pages.each do |p|
        f.write(p)
      end
    end
  end    

  def create_json(obj, file = 'policy.json')
    data = JSON.generate(obj)
    File.open(file, 'w') { |d| d.write(data)}
  end

  # Outline the text document to create JSON object
  def outline(doc)
    json     = {}
    i        = 0
    document = File.open(doc, 'a+')

    document.each_line do |f|
      # Get rid of extra whitespace
      line = f.strip
      next if line.empty?
      next if line == ""

      # Find the headings for each section by counting words
      # and checking them.
      words = line.split(" ")

      # Document headings are all caps and short. Lines that are capitalized
      # are the start of a paragraph. Lines not capitalized are
      # part of previous data sentence, so append them.
      if is_upper?(line) 
        json["title#{i}"] = line
      else
        json["data#{i}"] = line unless is_lower?(line[0])
        if is_lower?(line[0]) 
          json.values.last.concat(line)
        end
      end
      i+= 1
    end

    # Create JSON file from this object and write to file.
    create_json(json)
  end

end
```

EDIT:

- Appended missing code `unless is_lower?(line[0])` to the if statement
  next to `json['data#{i}']`
- Link to the object returned with this
  code:  http://www.jsonmate.com/permalink/54ed43e78622dbdf0c4232b6

Comment: can you post a sample of the returning object?

Comment: Yes, thanks for mentioning that. I'll add it to the OP. Also just saw a line from the original code was missing and I appended that data as well (see OP).